# Prove that $Y$ which has at least cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, is path connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set and $\tau=\lbrace A\subset X : A = \emptyset \quad \text{or} \quad   X \setminus A \quad \text{is  finite}\rbrace$.  Let $Y$ be a subspace of the topological space $(X,\tau)$. Show that if the cardinality of $Y$ is at least the cardinality of 
$\mathbb{R}$, then $Y$ is path connected.

Comment: I don't quite understand the statement of the problem. For example, $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $Y=(-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)$. Then is $Y$ path connected? There seems no way to construct a path from $-1$ to $2$ even if it is not assigned the ordinary topology.

Comment: @Golbez the thing to note is that the OP is asking about a set $X$ with the [cofinite topology](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Cofinite_topology), which behaves rather counter-intuitively. You're correct that $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$ is *not* path-connected in the usual topology on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @MorganO OK, I've got it! Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to answering this question is to prove that a cofinite or empty subset of $[0,1]$ is open in the usual topology. Given this if $x,y\in Y$ are arbitrary, then since $|Y|\geq |\mathbb{R}|$ there is an injective function $f:[0,1]\to Y$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$. If $U$ is any non-empty open set in $Y$, then $Y\setminus U$ is finite and so $f^{-1}(U)$ is cofinite in $[0,1]$. Hence by the key step at the start $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $[0,1]$ and so $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbb{I}$ denote the topological space that has $\left[0,1\right]$
as underlying set and is equipped with its usual topology. Let $u,v\in Y$.
A function $p:\mathbb{I}\rightarrow Y$ will be continuous if $p^{-1}\left(A\right)\subset\left[0,1\right]$
is closed for any finite set $A\subset Y$. Consequently every injection
is continuous (then $p^{-1}\left(A\right)$ is also finite, hence closed
in $\mathbb{I}$). If the cardinality of $Y$ is at least the cardinality
of $\left[0,1\right]$ then an injection can be constructed with $p\left(0\right)=u$
and $p\left(1\right)=v$.